# Use '$' instead of '.' for inner classes

Tags: android, view

The warning/error message (Use '$' instead of '.' for inner classes) was thrown when I tried to create a custom view element inside java sub class.

I tried to make it like so :

```
<com.example.myapp.CustomClass.Layout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error it had to be written the following way:

```
<view class="com.example.myapp.CustomClass$Layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...>
```